# CKEditor not loading entities plugin

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to include the `entities` plugin in my CDN version of CKEditor, but it's not loading.  Here's my initialization script:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('pbckcode',ROOT_URL+'assets/editor_plugins/pbckcode/');
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('entities',ROOT_URL+'assets/editor_plugins/entities/');

CKEDITOR.replace('docs-editor',{
    allowedContent: true,
    contentsCss:['https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                  ROOT_URL+'assets/editor.css'],
    extraPlugins:'pbckcode,entities',
    on:{
        instanceReady:function(ev){
            setFocus();
        },
    },
    pbckcode:{
        highlighter: 'PRETTIFY',
        modes: [
            [
                'PHP',
                'php'
            ]
            ,[
                'CSS',
                'css'
            ]
            ,[
                'Javascript',
                'javascript'
            ]
        ],
        theme: 'monokai'
    }
});
```

The `pbckcode` plugin gets loaded, but `entities` is not.  I believe I've verified the path to `entities/plugin.js` properly, so I'm not sure why `pbckcode` is loading, but `entities` is not.

I'm verifying by entering `CKEDITOR.plugins.loaded` in the console.

Comment: Does the browser console report any error? What is the value of ROOT_URL?

Comment: There is no console error.  I don't know what ROOT_URL is exactly, but since it's used in the pbckcode plugin and editor CSS urls, I know it's valid.

Comment: Instead of `CKEDITOR.plugins.loaded` , can you check with `CKEDITOR.plugins.externals` ?